# Why arguments in all JavaScript Documentation are written like this?

Tags: javascript

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

All over MDN, the documentation represents arguments like this `value[, replacer[, space]]`. What is the reason behind it?

What are the purpose of the square brackets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Square brackets are used by a lot of programming environments, command line tools and documentation to show that arguments are optional.

The double brackets mean that supplying one of the optional arguments doesn't force you to provide a value for the others.

That means that `replacer` is optional, and if you provide it, `space` is optional again, and that you can't specify `space` without specifying `replacer`.

This opposed to: (sample)

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer, space])
```

Where you need to provide a value for `space` if you provide a value for `replacer`.

Comment: … and that you can't specify space without specifying replacer.

Comment: Thanks for the not-nested example. Haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

It's a convention. Simple as that. In this case square brackets denote optional arguments, meaning only the argument `value` is really required.